# One to One relationship serializing in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following `User`,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the following `UserProfile` model,

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    level = models.CharField(default="Noob", max_length=255)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

The User has a one to one relationship with `Profile`.
This is the `UserSerializer`,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'mobile', 'username', 'full_name', 'password', 'is_active', 'profile',

        )
```

And this is the profile serializer.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('level', 'reputation', 'status',)
```

The issue is that in the serialized output for the user there is no nested profile data. How do I fix this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your `fields` contains an empty string?

Comment: That's a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

all you need is set [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) for `profile`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(source='userprofile', read_only=True)
```

the `userprofile` is name of relation of your model `User` by onetoone to the `UserProfle`, other way you can set `related_name` for attribute `user` in the 
`UserProfle`.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then your serializer will work fine as is.

Comment: Wow this worked magically. Now the question, where does this string 'userprofile' come from, what does it even mean?

Comment: @MelissaStewart it is model name